# How to fetch all method name which are defined in web service in ASP. NET

Tags: c#, web-services

Is there any way to fetch on the method at client side from webservice

Comment: Why do you need it? What kind of service is it.. Rest? WCF? I'd prefer tooling to generate documentation like swashbuckle (see answer below) or publishing a wsdl. But you can always create a method in your service that returns endpoint information using reflection to discover the available methods. But it depends on the why...

Comment: The reason behind that is for testing of my all methods I will Fetch the name of all method from webservice in a dropdown at client side and there I will select the name and create n activator for that which will hit the selected method in web service in that way I don't need to create a 1000 button for testing my 1000 methods in web service

Comment: In that case you should expose a method on your service that uses reflection to return a list of service methods the client can call.

Comment: If it's WCF and all you want to do is test the methods, look at WCF Test Client. It does exactly what you are asking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Peter do you have any demo code of algorithm for that reflection method if yes then can you please is it over there

Answer (score 1):

Swashbuckle - Swagger for WebApi will generate pages documenting your api methods for you.  You can customize it later if you need to.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle

Comment: But I am using web service. I have already added a proxy of my web service at client but now I want to use non public members cache property which contains method property to get the list of all methods